# How can I extract table values using python and lxml?

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, lxml

I need to extract list of IP addresses and port number as well as other information in the following html table, I am using python 2.7 with lxml currently, but have no idea how to find the proper path to these elements,

here is the address to table:
[link to table](https://hidester.com/proxylist/)

Comment: Are there multiple rows in this table?

Answer (score 0):

If the proxy.IP, proxy.PORT and proxy.country values are located in the same [n] cell location you can set that by specifying the location of the td[n] within the tr row:

```
from lxml import html

webpage = html.parse('lxml_test.html')

ip = webpage.xpath('//tr[@class="ng-scope"]/td[2]/text()')
port = webpage.xpath('//tr[@class="ng-scope"]/td[3]/text()')
proxy = webpage.xpath('//tr[@class="ng-scope"]/td[4]/text()')
```

Alternatively, if you're specifically after the cell names:

```
ip = webpage.xpath('//tr[@class="ng-scope"]/td[@ng-bind="proxy.IP"]/text()')
port = webpage.xpath('//tr[@class="ng-scope"]/td[@ng-bind="proxy.PORT"]/text()')
proxy = webpage.xpath('//tr[@class="ng-scope"]/td[@ng-bind="proxy.country"]/text()')
```

**EDIT**: To obtain the html code from a webpage use the requests module:

```
import requests
page = requests.get('https : //hidester.com/proxylist/')
webpage = html.fromstring(page.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are multiple rows in table, you can find each row then extract the data.

```
import lxml.etree

doc = lxml.etree.parse('test.xml')

# We need to locate the <tr> objects somehow... I'm assuming
# there is a single <table><tbody>.. container and no other
# span/div tags in the way.

for tr in doc.xpath('//table/tbody[1]/tr'):
    proxy_ip = tr.xpath('td[@ng-bind="proxy.IP"]/text()')[0].strip()
    proxy_port = tr.xpath('td[@ng-bind="proxy.PORT"]/text()')[0].strip()
    proxy_country = tr.xpath('td[@ng-bind="proxy.country"]/text()')[0].strip()
    print(proxy_ip, proxy_port, proxy_country)
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not output any of the values, im looking into it to see why that is the case, also how do you get the xpath in above? this is the webpage i am trying to crawl "https://hidester.com/proxylist/"

Comment: I created a valid xml document from your example and it did work. But I had to guess where that <tr> element is. Perhaps you could post a more complete document... and just a link to a 404 Page Not Found. You would want to thin out most of the cruft to get something small yet representative.

Comment: thank you, here is the updated link to the page:  https     :      //hidester.com/proxylist/

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup will help.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
header = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) '
                    'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                    'Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'}

url = str(raw_input("Enter URL: "))

req = requests.get(url,headers= header) #if the site dont require a request 
                                        #you dont have to ask for
html = req.text                         #if you dont want to ask for a 
                                        #request use mechanize module

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

for ip in soup.findAll("td",{"ng-binding":"proxy.IP"}):
    print "IP:      ", ip.get_text()

for ip_p in soup.findAll("td", {"ng-bind":"proxy.PORT"}):
    print "PORT:    ", ip_p.get_text()

for ip_c in soup.findAll("td", {"ng-bind":"proxy.country"}):
    print "COUNTRY: ", ip_c.get_text()
```